# HTML5 Validation error on Script?

Tags: javascript, html, mime-types

I have strange error on my HTML5 validation

```
Error: Bad value text for attribute type on element script: Subtype missing.

From line 316, column 1; to line 316, column 40

e="1" />↩↩<script id="viewModel" type="text">↩ {

Syntax of MIME type:
    A media-type as defined in RFC 2616; that is, typically, a required type, followed by a "/" character, followed by a required subtype, optionally followed by one or more instances of a ";" character followed by a parameter. Examples: text/css, text/css;charset=utf-8.
```

What i need to do to fix this error any idea?

Comment: For html5 you can simply remove the type attribute

Answer (score 1):

script type can not be pure text. it is followed by subtypes like this:

```
text/javascript
text/vbscript
```

etc.